# INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 USANDO PDO SQLITE3

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite3

Olá, já faz um tempo que venho pesquisando na internet inteira e tentando fazer funcionar essa query. No banco de dados funciona, porém, eu preciso fazer minha aplicação executar essa query, eu utilizo PDO no PHP para acessar o banco SQLITE3 desta forma:

```
  // Conexão a base de dados do coletor
  $pdoColetor = new PDO('sqlite:C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\downloadFiles\dbcoletor.s3db') or die("Erro ao abrir a base"); 

  // Conexão a base de dados dos 10 ultimos minutos do coletor
  $pdoUltimos10 = new PDO('sqlite:C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\downloadFiles\coleta.ultimo') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");
```

Então, eu tento executar a query para cada db porém não sei como "concatena-los" pois são objetos...

```
$sqlUltimos10min = $pdoUltimos10->query('SELECT * from DEVICES');

$sqlAtualizaColetor = $pdoColetor->query('INSERT INTO devices ');
```

Alguém saberia me informar a sintaxe correta ou tem alguma ideia de como eu consigo fazer isso usando PDO? No SQLiteStudio eu executo assim e funciona:

```
insert into dbcoletor.devices SELECT * from coleta.devices;
```

Teria algum meio de fazer isso pelo PDO Sqlite? Me desculpem se cometi algum erro ou não expressei da maneira correta a minha dúvida. Agradeço a atenção...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que essa primeira query "SELECT * FROM DEVICES" é um array, então teria que passar os valores para um array... tenta assim:

```
  foreach($sqlUltimos10min as $valor) {
      //$pdoColetor1 = db::getInstance();
      $sql10min = $pdoColetor->prepare("INSERT INTO DEVICES (coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4) VALUES (? ,? ,? ,? )");
      $sql10min->bindParam(1, $valor["nome_coluna1"]);
      $sql10min->bindParam(2, $valor["nome_coluna2"]);
      $sql10min->bindParam(3, $valor["nome_coluna3"]);
      $sql10min->bindParam(4, $valor["nome_coluna4"]);
      $sql10min->execute();
    }
```

Referência: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

Comment: obrigado, adaptei ao meu código e finalmente obtive algum avanço...